# Writing Lines to a Different File

Tags: python, file-writing

I am reading content from a file (scores.txt) and I have formatted the data that I need from it and I would like to write those lines to a new file. The new file I will be writing to is top_scores.txt. Below is the code for the desired output. I am just not entirely sure how to print to the file.

```
infile = open('scores.txt', 'r')
lineList = sorted(infile.readlines())

for lines in lineList:
    newLine = lines.replace('\n', '')
    splitLines = newLine.split(',')
    studentNames = splitLines[0]
    studentScores = splitLines[1:]
    studentsList = []
    for i in studentScores:
        studentsList.append(int(i))
    topScore = max(studentsList)
    print(studentNames.capitalize() + ': ', studentsList, 'max score =', int(topScore))
```

Sample from scores.txt:

> Pmas,95,72,77,84,86,81,74,\n

Sample for desired input for new file:

> Pmas: [95,72,77,84,86,81,74], max score = 95\n

Comment: Could you remove the unrelevant comments, uncomment the relevant ones and add a sample of what top_score.txt could be? I guess for instance that `lineList` assignation shouldn't be commented since you use `lineList` in your for loop.

Comment: Multiple errors. 


1. You have defined the function and haven't called it. i.e. `maxScore('a.txt')`
2. `infile2` and `lineList` should be marked `global`.
3. `.write` accepts only one argument, right?

Comment: ERRATUM : About what **scores.txt** could look like*. To be short, could you add a minimal, complete and verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should probably indent `infile2.write(studentName....` if you want it to run once per loop, though I can't see that causing the bugs you are describing.

Comment: @vmonteco Sure, sorry about that. I removed my comments. A sample of my top score when writing to the file would be: Pmas: [95,72,77,84,86,81,74], max score = 95\n

Comment: @Pmas You had to uncomment some of these rather than deleting them : Now, where is your `lineList` variable declared? You should also add a call to your function as @hexmint suggested. Plus, I don't see any use for the filename parameter for your `maxScore()` function. What is the point of your `float(i)` call? Correct your code please, there are too many errors that aren't related to your current problem.

Comment: @vmonteco I have changed the question slightly to show the code I originally created with the intent to print to the new file. I hope this one is clearer. I have only just started trying to learn Python.

Comment: @Pmas Yeah, that makes it a lot clearer and should take care of an undefined variable or two

Comment: @Pmas But how do you try to write the result into a file now?

Comment: @vmonteco I am wondering what the proper way to do that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a correct way to achieve what you want :

```
with open("scores.txt", 'r') as infile, open("top_score.txt", 'w') as outfile, open("top_score2.txt", '\
w') as outfile2:
    lineList = sorted(infile.readlines())
    for lines in lineList:
        newLine = lines.replace('\n', '')
        splitLines = newLine.split(',')
        studentNames = splitLines[0]
        studentScores = splitLines[1:]
        studentsList = []
        for i in studentScores:
            if i == '':
                break
            studentsList.append(int(i))
        topScore = max(studentsList)
        result = "%s: %s,max score = %d" % (studentNames.capitalize(),
                                            str(studentsList),
                                            max(studentsList))
        print(result)
        print(result, file = outfile)
        outfile2.write(result + "\n")
```

Note that I used two ways to print the result :

- `print()` file parameter.
- `file.write()` method.

Also note that I used a `with` statement like jDo suggested.

This way, it permits to open a file and to automatically close it when exiting the block.

**EDIT :**

Here is a version that is even shorter :

```
with open("scores.txt", 'r') as infile, open("top_score.txt", 'w') as outfile, open("top_score2.txt", 'w') as outfile2:
    lineList = sorted(infile.readlines())
    for lines in lineList:
        lines = lines.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        studentScores = lines[1:-1]
        studentsList = [int(i) for i in studentScores]
        result = "%s: %s,max score = %d" % (lines[0].capitalize(),
                                            str(studentsList),
                                            max(studentsList))
        print(result)
        print(result, file = outfile)
        outfile2.write(result + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @vmonteco ! I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*"(...) the variables I have defined to hold the data I need, are not defined (...)"*

Maybe that's caused by lines like these:

```
for i in studentScores:
    float(i)
```

`float(i)` doesn't  convert the value of `i` in a "lasting" way unless you assign a variable to it; e.g. do `score = float(i)` or whatever you want to call it. You can then work with `score` which is now a floating point number.

When writing to files, like in the line below, you have to write a single string at a time. When you place a comma between the values, they won't be combined into a single string so python will most likely fail with a `TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (x given)`.

```
infile2.write(studentNames.capitalize() + ': ', studentsList, 'top score =', int(topScore))
```

If `studentNames` and `studentsList` are `list`s and `int(topScore)` is an integer, none of the variables can be written to a file as is. You will need to select individual strings from your `list`s (e.g. `studentNames[0]`) or use `" ".join(name_of_your_list)` to combine all elements into a single string. `int(topScore)` will have to be converted to a string via `str(topScore)`.

*"I am just not entirely sure how to print to the file."*

The easiest way to handle file reading/writing is via `with open(filename, mode) handle:`. E.g.:

```
with open("output_file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(some_string)
```

Just some observations that'll explain at least *some* of the errors you're probably getting...

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file just use :

```
file = open("top_score.txt", "a")
str=', '.join(str(x) for x in studentsList)
file.write(studentNames.capitalize() +'\t'+str+'\t'+(topScore))
file.close();
```